# How shall i build up my own proxy server?

Tags: php, proxy-server

I want to build up my own proxy server . Whats the procedure to start that ? What are the steps ? I am Good in PHP and i have my own web server,

Please Guide me ,for building up a proxy server that handles PHP page's as well

I just want to know the basics!  There are many Proxy Site's that say " Access facebook from School"   So how do they work ? Can i also create something like that ? !

If i use `file_get_contents()` function and display it on the screen  it can be used as a static WEBPAGE proxy.

So my question was simple, 
How can i develop something that can be used for accessing Facebook ?

Comment: Wow, this question is really vague. Please ask **specific** questions. If *must* ask a broad/general questions, then at the very least provide background information on what you're trying to accomplish and where exactly you reach a stage where you don't know what to do...

Answer (score 1):

SSH port forwarding should get you want you want.

http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/ssh-tunnel.html

Edit:  The relevant info from the site:

```
ssh -L 8888:www.linuxhorizon.ro:80 user@computer -N 
ssh -L 8888:www.linuxhorizon.ro:80 -L 110:mail.linuxhorizon.ro:110 \ 
25:mail.linuxhorizon.ro:25 user@computer -N
```

By setting this up on a server, you allow yourself to access the information from anywhere via your server's IP.  This provides a workaround if the domain is blocked, but your server's is not.

Comment: How do you know the answer to this question when you cannot know the question itself? How do you know that's what he's looking for .... ? The question is so vague it can mean anything from writing his own HTTP proxy software to setting up a HTTP proxy to setting up a SSH tunnel ...

Comment: Did you really downvote me because I made an effort to help him?

Comment: Of course not :-) To quote the FAQ "If you see misinformation, vote it down". IMHO this qualifies as misinformation because as I see it you cannot possibly know the answer since at the moment the question is phrased in such an ambiguous manner it can mean any number of things, so *any* answer qualifies as "misinformation" IMHO.

Comment: There are many Proxy Site's that say " Access facebook from School"   So how do they work ? Can i also create something like that ? !

If i use `file_get_contents()` function and display it on the screen  it can be used as a static WEBPAGE proxy. 

So my question was simple, 
How can i develop something that can be used for accessing Facebook ?

Comment: My answer solves this question.
This works because your school is most likely denying popular websites (like facebook) instead of allowing traffic to white-listed domains.
Since traffic to/from your server will be trusted, you can setup port forwarding to get traffic from any website.  
P.S.  Carpetsmoker, quit smoking and read my answer.  SSH port forwarding can be used for ANY type of proxy, regardless of how ambiguous his question is.  Please don't downvote because you don't understand his question.  If we downvote every answer we don't understand, this site wouldn't work.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but I've read your answer, so how would that help answering the question? cuz it's quite big topic and start learning SSH 'might not' be that 'easy'.

Comment: To build a proxy server, you'll need basic understanding of internet routing because we're turning the web server into a form of a router.  If you provide a web interface to manage these commands (highly insecure and unadvised), you'll have a functional prototype that can be expanded on.

Answer (score 1):

Configure PHP on your webserver and install the PHP Proxy Software of your choice:

[http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=php+proxy&sortdir=desc&limit=25&sort=rating](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=php%20proxy&sortdir=desc&limit=25&sort=rating)

Make sure you can connect to the proxy from wherever you are and that it is outside of whatever firewall you are trying to get around.

Then add the server address of the proxy into your OS or browser's Proxy settings (which depends on the OS or Browser).

Comment: There are many Proxy Site's that say " Access facebook from School" So how do they work ? Can i also create something like that ? !

If i use file_get_contents() function and display it on the screen it can be used as a static WEBPAGE proxy.

So my question was simple, How can i develop something that can be used for accessing Facebook ?

Comment: The answer is that you don't need to develop anything new.  You only have to set up the proxy server on your webserver and then access it. Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?